# INI directive ‘mbstring.func_overload’ is deprecated since PHP 7.2

Tags: wordpress, php-5.6, php-7.2

Using PHP Compatibility Checker, got this warning

```
INI directive 'mbstring.func_overload' is deprecated since PHP 7.2
```

is there any way to handle this warning?

Answer (score 0):

It all might depend on how your code is using this. [PHP.net highly discourages using this feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php). If you are using an older library that uses this value, then you should look at updating the library and see if they've fixed it. If that library or your code is accessing this value (for example with `ini_get('mbstring.func_overload')`), then that's not really a problem, though the compatibility parser will still call it out as an issue. [This was called out to the Symfony maintainers](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31686), and they just dismissed it.